# Sorting on key having chars and numbers

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I am using the following code in my macro to sort on selected columns

```
Range("A14:CE" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Cells(14, Col), Cells(lastRow, Col)), 
_Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), Order2:=xlAscending, 
_Header:=xlNo
```

I just noticed that this can behave strangely when there are numbers at the the end of the cell, like in this example

[image]

the data in the left column will be sorted from A to Z like in the right column, which is not what I want. 
I want to have 2 after 1, not 10! 
I checked and this is how Excel itself sorts. Is there a way to prevent it, other than changing the text to FM-001?

Comment: In short, no.  Excel sees it as text and thus goes character by character and the numbers are characters.  You can parse the values in another hidden column that is the `FM-001` then sort on that hidden column, but without parsing the string and adding the `00` it will not sort properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes scott is right you need 2 sepearate columns for text and numbers and then sort them ;

If this is the only combination then you can use

```
=LEFT(A1,2)

=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-5)
```

AND IF YOU HAVE NOT A COMMON PATTERN BUT TEXT FIRST AND THEN NUMBERS

```
=LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2&"0123456789"))-1)

=RIGHT(A4,LEN(A4)-MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A4&"0123456789"))+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

not having my laptop with me, but I will outline my thoughts below:

1. detect the cell length, if len = 4, then replace "-" with "-0"
2. sort the column
3. detect the 3rd place of the cell, if it's 0, then replace "-0" with "-"